# Making Daemon Thread to run till JVM Exits

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon, background-process

After reading throw Daemon threads and implementing according to my requirements raised several doubts.
Please clarify me

1. I am using ServletContextListener class to invoke a Daemon thread which needs to run unitl JVM exits

   ```
   public void contextInitialized (ServletContextEvent event) {

        context = event.getServletContext();
        //getting from spring context
        MyServiceManager serviceManager = (MyServiceManager) ctx.getBean("myServiceManager");
        serviceManager.setDaemon(true);
        serviceManager.start();    
   }
   ```
2. in ServiceManager class I am running an infinite loop to run the program foever until JVM exists

   ```
   public void run() {
       try {
           startService();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           logger.error("Error Occured in Background Process Runner");
       }
   }

   private void startService(){
       while(true){
          try{
           //invoke some new threads and do processing jobs until server/jvm stops
              }catch(Exception e) {
               //log but don't quit
              }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The concern is, will daemon thread with the above implmentation runs foever? if not, what should i do to achieve my job. Unless JVM stops (server stopped), tell it to not to quit.

Note: I am trying my level best to format this post. but today something is going, it's not getting formatted :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your daemon thread will run until the `run()` method terminates, either by exiting normally or by throwing an exception (or until the VM exits, which is what you want). Since you catch all exceptions thrown by `startService()`, it will run until `startService()` returns or throws an exception, and will then exit normally.

Be aware that if `startService()` is interrupted while it is waiting for I/O, sleeping, or in a wait state, then it will generally throw an `InterruptedException`. Well-behaved threads usually exit when they are interrupted, as this is the normal method for telling a thread to exit.

Note that marking the thread as a daemon only means that the VM will not wait until the thread exits before it shuts down. None of the other behavior regarding thread termination is affected by the thread being a daemon or not.

Comment: actually startService block has overall try catch exception wrapped around the loop. It will not throws any Exceptions. so i guess daemon thread should run forever.

What happens when server is stopped or JVM shut down. Deamon thread should be killed right. if not, is it possible to kill it from contextDestroyed methods of servlet?

Comment: @NitinGurram - When the JVM shuts down, all threads stop. Note that a daemon thread in the middle of I/O may be stopped without being given a chance to clean up properly. You should register a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) if you need to give the daemon thread a chance to clean up. The docs for that method have a detailed description of the shutdown process.